# POSTMAN client send correct JSON response but the Chrome browser receives HTML

Tags: json, reactjs, flask, frontend, backend

This sounds very absurd but I opened up an old React project of mine and the view does not render. Upon inspection, I found it is receiving a HTML response from the Flask server. However, I am sending valid JSON response to the frontend. This is evident from the POSTMAN client too which throws a JSON response.

So to summarise, Postman Client is receiving expected JSON response from Flask server BUT the Chrome browser is not ! How /Why is this happening ?

Attaching the screenshot below

[image: Unexpected behavior]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server and client are running on different ports. The Postman requests are sent to the port 5000 and any endpoint is relative to `localhost:5000` . Hence the response on Postman is as expected. However, for the React frontend to redirect its calls to the backend running on port 5000 , we need a way to tell the frontend to do so since endpoints are relative to the address on which they are running. Hence, an endpoint `/questions` for the server running on 5000 means `localhost:5000/questions` but for the frontend means `localhost:3000/questions` . This connection is provided by setting `proxy` on the `package.json` of your project. The value of the proxy would be the server address .

[image: Proxy on package.json]